# Generate and Save file to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, export-to-excel, binary-data

I have a record set (DataTable) that I am saving to Excel and then need to save to a database (as binary).

I have two parts working separately, but I can't figure out how to tie them both together without having to actually save a hard copy of the Excel to the disk.

Here is the "export to Excel" code:

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filename;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gvCompleteCases.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

and the "save file to database" snippet:

```
byte[] fileData = null;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
{
    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
    UploadFile.Upload2(GetD(), file.ContentLength, fu.FileBytes, numberOfPages);
}
```

The above example saves the file to user's machine and then I have to point to its location to save to the database, is there a way I can create the Excel file, without saving to user's hard disk, before saving it to the database?

I guess what I'm asking is how do I get the `fileData` of the created Excel, without saving it to the computer?

Comment: What type is `gvCompleteCases`?

Comment: And using this technique you are able to save a .xls file to the client computer and open it in Excel, and it works as expected?

Comment: You have not created an actual Excel file. You've created an HTML file and then served it up with Excel MIME type and presumably file extension.  You should create an actual XLSX file using a managed library such as EPPlus, NPOI, or Office XML SDK. Those should support creating a byte array without having to write a file to disc, then you can store that in the database (and write it to the response).

Comment: @JohnWu - yes it works, mason - thanks! i'll do some research on the bytearrays now

Comment: I guess Excel is more clever than I thought, and can parse HTML to make a spreadsheet.  Who knew?

Comment: @mason - i got it working using yoru suggestion, thanks! i'm saving a datatable as byte array to the database, and then converting that byte array to excel upon data retrieval! works great!